# Printing command output to file at timed interval

Tags: python, shell, timer, intervals, timed

I require the ability to print the output of a command to a single file at a timed interval.  The Python example I am working with is as follows:

```
import time
i = 0
print('START!')

while i >= 0:
        f = open('timelog.txt','a')
        nowstr = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
        print(nowstr)
        f.write(nowstr)
        f.write('\n')
        f.close()
        time.sleep(60)
        i = i + 1

print('DONE!');
```

The above code does what it needs to and prints the date and time to a single file every 60 seconds on a new line (does not overwrite existing entries or date).  I need to adapt that code to execute a shell command at a fixed interval (objective is to log shell command output to file at a timed interval).

Thank you.

Comment: "to execute a shell command versus the time"? Explain please.

Comment: You can try http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html to execute a command or try the https://github.com/kennethreitz/envoy library, a convenient wrapper around subprocess.